# What is Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am getting an error that says `SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0`
and I cannot find any information on what "a" means. I know that the JSON is not undefined.
Can anyone help me understand what is causing this error?

Here is the code block that is causing the error:

```
let db_creds = await getDBCredentials();
console.log(db_creds)
const pool = new Pool(JSON.parse(db_creds['SecretString']));
console.log(pool)
```

Comment: What do you see on the console from the console.log at second line?

Comment: @atiqorin ``` 
    {
      SecretString: 'arn:aws:SECRETSTRINGINEED'
    }
```

Comment: @wezrine You try to parse the string `arn:aws:SECRETSTRINGINEED` as JSON. It isn't valid JSON. The "token" (character) at position 0 (the very first), isn't a character that valid JSON can start with. Which is the "a".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unexpected Token < in JSON at Position 0. From time to time when working with JSON data, you might stumble into errors regarding JSON formatting. For instance, if you try to parse a malformed JSON with the JSON. ... json() method on the fetch object, it can result in a JavaScript exception being thrown.

[What Is JSON and How to Handle an “Unexpected Token” Error](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/what-is-json-how-to-handle-unexpected-token-error#:%7E:text=JavaScript-,Unexpected%20Token%20%3C%20in%20JSON%20at%20Position%200,malformed%20JSON%20with%20the%20JSON.&text=json()%20method%20on%20the,a%20JavaScript%20exception%20being%20thrown.)

Answer (score -1):

Well for me it was because the port was already in use and it must be sending HTML, you can try killing the port by running the below command in cmd(admin mode)

taskkill /F /IM node.exe

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).